# pdftoppm (v 3.0) very slow to convert thumbnail in newer version

Tags: pdf, conversion, image-manipulation

On one of our local servers, I use `pdftoppm` (v 0.18.4) to capture the first page of a pdf file as a 1200px wide jpg.  It's very quick, and works very well.  I'm doing it like so:

```
pdftoppm -f 1 -l 1 -scale-to-x 1200 -jpeg "$infile" "$outfile"
```

This is practically instantaneous in its execution.

On our live server, we have a more modern version of `pdftoppm` (v 3.00) and it takes a long time (between 30-70 seconds) to produce the thumbnail, which I'm doing like so:

```
pdftoppm -f 1 -l 1 -r 1200  "$infile" "$outfile"
```

This took 35 seconds and produced a 400 MB image which was nearly 10,000 px wide, so that's obviously not correct!  I can't seem to be able to control the resolution (which is obviously the source of the huge file size and conversion time), and I can't seem to be able to specify that the output is a jpg either:  passing the `-jpeg` option just makes pdftoppm output its options, which is the standard behaviour for "bad options given".

Can anyone tell me which options to pass to v 3.00 to get the same result as with the earlier version?

I think I should actually just try and downgrade our server version of `pdftoppm` to the same one I have locally, but before I do that I want to see if I'm missing something.  The man page for v3.00 is here:   http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftoppm

Answer (score 0):

I just experience this issue so I think I can contribute a little bit here. If you look at the document of [pdftoppm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftoppm), you will notice in the live server you are actually not scaling to 1200px, rather, you are setting the resolution to 1200 (default is 150) which explain the long processing time needed on your live server

```
    pdftoppm -f 1 -l 1 -r 1200  "$infile" "$outfile"
```

should be change to

```
    pdftoppm -f 1 -l 1 -scale-to 1200  "$infile" "$outfile"
```

instead which should provide you with the same speed as your dev server.

Comment: Ah - so i'd been setting it to 1200 pixels-per-inch?  That would explain the slowness!  Thanks  - i will try this.

Comment: @MaxWilliams if this is the answer, please vote it as answer. thanks

Comment: I've not had a chance to test it yet but if it works then i'll mark it as correct.  thanks

Comment: @MaxWilliams yes sir ;)